# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1

Tags: java, realm, keycloak

I'm creating groups using realm in keycloak so while calling Group resource method this error occured.

Stacktrace :

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:40)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:146)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:121)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:394)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:636)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.buildEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:601)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:479)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:307)
```

Comment: Thanks for the full stack trace. Can you explain what you're trying to do too, and show us the object you're trying to return or serialize, and the code that creates it? $1 normally means an anonymous inner class, but AFAICS javax.ws.rs.core.Form doesn't have any of those.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to add groups using keycloak realm methods which internally uses Rest Api but was not able to do so as it is throwing error in invoking the method.

Comment: [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715747/resteasy-providers-missing-after-mvn-package/52716124#52716124) may help you.