# Keycloak getAccessToken works in Java Eclipse/Maven project but throws ProcessingException running via commandline

Tags: java, eclipse, command, keycloak, resteasy

My Maven project in Eclipse retrieves an access token from our keycloak server when run in the Eclipse environment. When I compile a fat jar, which includes all the dependencies, the same code, running on the same JDK/JRE(1.8) throws a ProcessingException. What is throwing me for a loop is the fact that it works on the same computer via Eclipse (thin JAR) but not via the command line (fat JAR). Both environments use the same Java installation as well as the same libraries.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:325)
```

I have read through similar issues on stackoverflow and searched on the web for the exception as well as the RESTEASY codes. I have tried the following changes with no change in behavior...

1. Using jboss ApacheHttpClient4Engine vs. ResteasyClientBuilder
2. keycloak versions: 6.0.1, 7.0.1, 8.0.1

Code environment:

- OS: Windows 10
- Eclipse RCP release 2019-12
- Windows 10 commandline
- JDK 1.8.0_231 (the same installation of binaries and libraries for both commandline and eclipse)

The relevant section of the code, pom.xml, and the complete stack trace are below. Please let me know if more details will help. Thanks!

```
          if (!requireValidToken) return;

            keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                    .serverUrl(deployment.getAuthServerBaseUrl())
                    .realm(deployment.getRealm())
                    .username(username).password(passwd)
                    .clientId(deployment.getResourceName())
                    .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().build()).build();

            System.out.println("CODE ALWAYS THROWS AN EXCEPTION AT THE NEXT LINE");
            AccessTokenResponse tokenResponse = keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();   
            System.out.println("CODE ALWAYS THROWS AN EXCEPTION BEFORE THIS LINE");
            setAccessToken(tokenResponse.getToken());
            verifyToken(tokenResponse.getToken(), null, null, null);                    

        } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
```

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <keycloak.version>7.0.1</keycloak.version>
        <resteasy.version>3.7.0.Final</resteasy.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.9</jackson.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-installed-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.imagej/ij -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
            <artifactId>ij</artifactId>
            <version>1.49c</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openrdf/rio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesame-rio-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesame-rio-rdfxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
            <artifactId>sesame-rio-turtle</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The exception trace:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:325)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:443)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:149)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.grantToken(Unknown Source)
        at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:89)
        at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:69)
        at org.emile.cirilo.business.KeycloakProxy.<init>(KeycloakProxy.java:109)
        at org.emile.cirilo.fedora.FedoraConnector.stubOpenConnection(FedoraConnector.java:133)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:38)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:146)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:121)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:398)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:671)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.buildEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:636)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:514)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:313)
        ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late, but for a Maven project, look here:
[resteasy providers missing after mvn package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715747/resteasy-providers-missing-after-mvn-package/52716124#52716124)

As for Gradle project, the usage of [Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) is needed.

```
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()

    append 'META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers'
}
```